# Angular nested ng repeat scope with pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, pagination, angular-material

I am using angular with material lib. In project I have two nested loops of ng-repeat with md-tables. Problem is that in nested loops variable is ovveriden each time on each request. I could make one request and iterate, but I have dynamic pagination, and it will not work.

Here is index file with tables:

```
<div ng-init="getCategories()" flex>
...
 <div class="content-main"  ng-repeat="category in categories">
...
    <md-content>
        <table md-table ng-init="getBooks(category.id)">
           ...
           <tr md-row ng-repeat="book in books | orderBy: query.order ">
                <td md-cell>
                    <span>{{ book.title }}</span>
                </td>
    ...
    </md-content>
    <md-table-pagination md-limit="query.limit"
                         md-limit-options="limit"
                         md-page="query.page"
                         md-page-select="options.pageSelect"
                         md-total="{{booksCount}}"
                         md-boundary-links="options.boundaryLinks">
    </md-table-pagination>
```

Simplified angular controller functions:

```
$scope.getCategories = function () {
 \\get request
  $scope.categories = resp.data.rows;
  }

$scope.getBooks = function () {
 \\get request with pagination and search params
   $scope.books = resp.data.rows;
   $scope.booksCount = resp.data.amount;
  }
```

So every request getBooks ovverides "books" variable, and now for example I have two categories abd I see same books (from category 2) for both.

```
Category 1
 Book C Book D
Category 2 
 Book C Book D
(wrong)
```

But I have for Category 1 another books:

```
Category 1
 Book A Book B
Category 2 
 Book C Book D
 (correct)
```

Comment: are you really passing the `category.id` on your `getBooks` method?

Comment: yes, i see i in debugger two requests with correct `category.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you have an `ng-init` inside your `ng-repeat` which sets `$scope.books` for each iteration where last one ends up overwriting all previous instances of `$scope.books`.

I would recommend following changes to your code:

- Instead of using `ng-init` inside `ng-repeat`, call `getBooks` directly from the success callback inside `getCategories`. Usage of `ng-init` is discouraged and also considered bad practice. So, something like this:

  ```
  $scope.getBooks = function (categoryId) {
    // get request with pagination and search params
    $scope.books[categoryId] = resp.data.rows;
    $scope.booksCount[categoryId] = resp.data.amount;
  }

  $scope.getCategories = function () {
    //get request
    $scope.categories = resp.data.rows;
    $scope.books = {};
    $scope.booksCount = {};
    $scope.categories.forEach(function(category) {
      $scope.getBooks(category.id)
    })
  }

  $scope.getCategories();
  ```
- Now your HTML would look like this:

  ```
  <div flex>
  ...
  <div class="content-main" ng-repeat="category in categories">
  ...
    <md-content>
      <table md-table>
      ...
        <tr md-row ng-repeat="book in books[category.id] | orderBy: query.order">
          <td md-cell>
              <span>{{ book.title }}</span>
          </td>
          ...
    </md-content>
  ```

That should be working fine.. unless it has any silly mistake since there is no *verifiable* example provided

Answer (score 1):

You should change your controller first like this :

```
 $scope.getCategories = function () {
            //get request
            $scope.categories = resp.data.rows;
            angular.forEach($scope.categories, function (category, index) {
                $scope.getBooks(category);
            });
        }();

        $scope.getBooks = function(category) {
             // make request by passing category.id.
            //get request with pagination and search params
            $scope.category = resp.data;

        };
```

And your HTML will look like :

```
<div flex>
...
 <div class="content-main"  ng-repeat="category in categories">
...
    <md-content>
        <table md-table>
           ...
           <tr md-row ng-repeat="book in category.rows | orderBy: query.order ">
                <td md-cell>
                    <span>{{ book.title }}</span>
                </td>
    ...
    </md-content>
```